# GMT date and time to convert Local device Date Time?

Tags: android

hi I got web service result  6/26/2013 12:00:00 AM from GMT how to make convert to local device time.Please give me solution

I have implement this code but not working

```
public static String DateTime(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    return dateformat.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the timezone to your formatter before parsing the date.

```
public static String DateTime(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); //Will return your device current time zone
    dateformat.setTimeZone(tz); //Set the time zone to your simple date formatter
    return dateformat.format(date);
}
```